# SABRE Bargain Finder Max

Tags: api, soap, sabre

I'm working with Bargain Finder Max Sabre SOAP method, i'm always getting response version is deprecated but i'm specifying the Request Version="3.4.0" and ResponseVersion="3.4.0".

My request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" Target="Test" Version="3.4.0" ResponseType="OTA" ResponseVersion="3.4.0">
   <POS>
      <Source PseudoCityCode="xxxx">
         <RequestorID Type="1" Instance="1" ID="1" />
      </Source>
   </POS>
   <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1">
      <DepartureDateTime>2018-01-15T00:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
      <OriginLocation LocationCode="YYZ" />
      <DestinationLocation LocationCode="SDQ" />
   </OriginDestinationInformation>
   <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="2">
      <DepartureDateTime>2018-01-18T00:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
      <OriginLocation LocationCode="SDQ" />
      <DestinationLocation LocationCode="YYZ" />
   </OriginDestinationInformation>
   <TravelerInfoSummary>
      <AirTravelerAvail>
         <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
      </AirTravelerAvail>
      <PriceRequestInformation CurrencyCode="USD" />
   </TravelerInfoSummary>
   <TPA_Extensions>
      <IntelliSellTransaction>
         <RequestType Name="50ITIN" />
      </IntelliSellTransaction>
   </TPA_Extensions>
</OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header />
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="1.0">
         <Errors>
            <Error Type="SRV.DRE" Code="REQ.FLR" ShortText="dre request failed" />
            <Error Type="IF2" Code="PROCESS" ShortText="PROCESSING ERROR DETECTED" />
            <Error Type="MAIN" Code="DEPRECATEDRS" ShortText="This response version is deprecated and will be decommissioned once a newer version is released." />
            <Error Type="WORKERTHREAD" Code="TRANSACTIONID" ShortText="6572224660929009932" />
            <Error Type="SERVER" Code="TTFHLC850" ShortText="27042" />
            <Error Type="ERR" Code="ERR" ShortText="Error during Processing" />
         </Errors>
      </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is missing the company name under the “RequestorID”.  This element should be filed with a concrete value.

Expected in the request:

```
   <POS>
      <Source PseudoCityCode="xxxx">
         <RequestorID Type="1" Instance="1" ID="1">
       <CompanyName Code="TN"/>
       </RequestorID>
      </Source>
   </POS>
```

As a consequence of not having this element “CompanyName“ in the request, the transaction failed, defaulted the response to version="1.0" and the returned the warning saying that the version is deprecated. This is something being reviewed to enhance, but should resolve the problem.

http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/shopping/BargainFinderMaxRQ_v3-4-0_Design.xml